# Laravel on Linux debian server VPS: You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I deployed a Laravel app on a VPS server Linux Debian. But I get a message in my web page like:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

I tried many configuration specially my `laravel.conf` located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and my `.htaccess` located in my project root level.

I also tried command bellow:

```
sudo find /var/www/html/laravel_app -type d -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/laravel_app/storage -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

I've been working on it for a week. I tried many others answers from stackoverflow without success.

Here my `laravel.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:3000>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel_app
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel_app>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here bellow my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html/laravel_app`, but Laravel's `index.php` is in a dir named `public`.  It looks like your `DocumentRoot` points to your Laravel root directory, but there is no `index.php` there.  And if you have not enabled directory listing with `+Indexes` ... there's nothing Apache can do so you'll get a permission denied.

Comment: I tried DocumentRoot with /var/www/html/laravel_app/public and also added `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks`. But I still have 403 forbidden problem in web page. I tried to restart apache2 with `sudo systemctl restart apache2` too.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` still in `public/`?  Also until it is working, keep things simple - remove `*:3000`.  Remove `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from all`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Did you also update `<Directory /var/www/html/laravel_app/public>`?

Comment: My index.php is located in laravel_app/public directory and my .htaccess is located in laravel_app/ directory

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, and as my answer describes, `.htaccess` is supposed to be in `public/`.  Do not move it.

Comment: I moved .htaccess file in `public/` directory. I also updated `<Directory /var/www/html/laravel_app/public>`. But still not working.

Comment: But in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory I got many config files like `ispconfig.conf` or `laravel.conf` and more. I tried `sudo a2ensite laravel.conf` and then restart apache2 but still not working. I tried `sudo a2dissite ispconfig.conf`

Comment: If you have more vhosts, you should include a `ServerName`, to make sure you are even using this `laravel.conf`.  Or you could try temporarily disabling your other config files to check if that is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html/laravel_app`, but Laravel's `index.php` is in [a dir named `public`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/structure#the-public-directory).

It looks like your `DocumentRoot` points to your Laravel root directory, but there is no `index.php` there.  And if you have not [enabled directory listing with `+Indexes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options) ... there's nothing Apache can do so you'll get a permission denied.

Update your root to point to Laravel's `public` dir:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:3000>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel_app/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel_app/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE**

You mention "*my .htaccess located in my project root level*" - if you really mean you have moved `.htaccess` from `laravel_app/public/.htaccess` to `laravel_app/.htaccess`, don't do that.  [As the docs say](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment):

> You should never attempt to move the index.php file to your project's root, as serving the application from the project root will expose many sensitive configuration files to the public Internet:

**NOTE 2**

You are mixing old and new directives in your Apache config.  [From the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#access):

> **Mixing old and new directives**
>
> Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like Require is technically possible but discouraged.

This is Apache 2.2 config, and should be removed:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

That is superceded by the Apache 2.4 config equivalent, which you correctly already have:

```
Require all granted
```

**NOTE 3**

As I mentioned in the comments, if you have more than one vhost, you should be [using `ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) so that Apache can work out which host config to use for an incoming request.  If you only really have this one Laravel vhost, disable all others.

Comment: Hi, It seems that another config file is used. Even if I run `sudo a2ensite laravel.conf` and then restart apache2. I tried your config wihtout success. But I saw that when I edit a file named default-ssl.conf located in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory, my website show all my laravel applications folder.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, if you have more than one vhost, you should be using ServerName so that Apache can work out which host config to use for an incoming request. If you only really have this one Laravel vhost, disable all others.

Answer (score 0):

try this structure:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@site
     ServerName laravel_app
     ServerAlias www.laravel_app.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel_app/public
     DirectoryIndex index.php

     <Directory /var/www/laravel_app/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     Require all granted
     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_app_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/laravel_app_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

as said in the comments, you should add public directory because it contains the index.php file to be rendered.
wish that helps you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem that caused permission access error. In my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory I had already another vhost config file called `default-ssl.conf`. And for an unknown reason that was this file my server executed and not vhost file that I created and enabled with `sudo a2ensite laravel.conf` . So I edited that file and used @Don't Panic answer to configure.
Another problem was related to my .htaccess as you mentioned. I moved .htaccess and placed it in laravel_app/public directory.
I had to excute these command below also to grant permission :

```
sudo find /var/www/html/laravel_app -type d -exec chmod 755 -R {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/laravel_app -type f -exec chmod 644 -R {} \;
```

Here below my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Here below my default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel_app/public
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel_app/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php    
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now it works fine.
But I have a message like Insecure connection in this site. I will look for in another discussion or documentation. I think to SSL config problem.
Thank's to everyone, really appreciate and sorry for my english!